# How can I select a part of rows and create a new table in HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a large table in HBase, I want to separate them into several small tables, so that it will be easier for me to use. (The original table should be kept.) How can I do that?

For example: I have a table, called `all` with following rowkey:

```
animal-1, ...
plant-1, ...
animal-2, ...
plant-2, ...
human-1, ...
human-2, ...
```

I want to separate it to three tables: `animal`,`plant`,`human` for the three type of living beings. How can I do it?

Comment: MultipleTableOutputFormat can seve this purpose. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mapreduce with [MultipleTableOutputFormat](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/MultiTableOutputFormat.html) like the below example.

But in the below example I am reading from the file i.e `TextInputFormat` instead you have to read it from Hbase table using `TableInputFormat` `'all'` instead of table1 table2 ... you have to use `'animal', 'planet', 'human'`

As per your requirement, if you do a scan on Hbase table and pass it to Mapper using table InputFormat, you will get rowkey as well to Mapper's map method. This you need to compare to decide which table you are going to insert.

[Please see 7.2.2. HBase MapReduce Read/Write Example](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html)

```
package mapred;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MultiTableOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
public class MultiTableMapper {
static class InnerMapper extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {
public void map(LongWritable offset, Text value, Context context) throws IOException {
// contains the line of tab separated data we are working on (needs to be parsed out).
//byte[] lineBytes = value.getBytes();
String valuestring[]=value.toString().split(“\t”);
String rowid = /*HBaseManager.generateID();*/ “12345”;
// rowKey is the hbase rowKey generated from lineBytes
Put put = new Put(rowid.getBytes());
put.add(Bytes.toBytes(“UserInfo”), Bytes.toBytes(“StudentName”), Bytes.toBytes(valuestring[0]));
try {
context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(“Table1”)), put);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} // write to the actions table
// rowKey2 is the hbase rowKey
Put put1 = new Put(rowid.getBytes());
put1.add(Bytes.toBytes(“MarksInfo”),Bytes.toBytes(“Marks”),Bytes.toBytes(valuestring[1]));
// Create your KeyValue object
//put.add(kv);
try {
context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(“Table2”)), put1);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} // write to the actions table
}
}
public static void createSubmittableJob() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
Path inputDir = new Path(“in”);
Configuration conf = /*HBaseManager.getHBConnection();*/ new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, “my_custom_job”);
job.setJarByClass(InnerMapper.class);
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputDir);
job.setMapperClass(InnerMapper.class);
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
// this is the key to writing to multiple tables in hbase
job.setOutputFormatClass(MultiTableOutputFormat.class);
//job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
//TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);
//TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job.getConfiguration());
System.out.println(job.waitForCompletion(true));
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
MultiTableMapper.createSubmittableJob();
System.out.println();
}
}
```